# Handling Json data outside a function with pebble.js

Tags: ajax, json, pebble-watch, cloudpebble, pebble-js

In the function **getweather()** I do fetch some weather data from a Json-object and store that data in the variable **data**. Within that function, I can handle the Json-data, but how do I access the data from outside of **getweather()**?

It doesn't matter if i return the variable **location** or **data**. The variable **place** is just not Json.

How do I handle the **place** variable in order to make it work as it does within the function **getweather()**?

```
var ajax = require('ajax');

var place;
place = getweather();

function getweather()
{
    // Make the request
    ajax(
    {
      url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=paris.fr', type: 'json'
   },
    function(data) 
    {
    // Success!
    console.log("Successfully fetched weather data!");

    // Extract data
        var location = data.name;
        return location;    

    },
    function(error) {
    // Failure!
    console.log('Failed fetching weather data: ' + error);
    }
  );    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The A in AJAX stands for asynchronous.  What's happening in your code is that you are trying to assign a value to `place` before the asynchronous call to api.openweather.org has returned.

You can check this by placing a statement like `console.log(place);` directly after `place = getweather();`. You will notice in the console that `None` is returned before you see `Successfully fetched weather data!`

This issue has been described in detail in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). It recommends restructuring your code around your callbacks.